# find nth+n element in a list

Tags: python, excel, list

I have a string of numbers (23,24,25,26,22,23,25 etc.) that represent x,y,z coordinates over time:  0=x1, 1=y1, 2=z1, 3=x2, 4=y2, 5=z2,

where x1=postion at time 1 and x2=position at Time 2.

I want to be able to isolate the xs, the ys and the zs.

I can isolate xs with:

```
def giveXs(list):
answer=(list[::3])
return answer
```

but

```
def giveYs(list):
answer=(list[::3]+1)
return answer
```

or

```
def giveZs(list): 
answer=(list[::3+2])
return answer
```

is clearly not correct.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For x:

```
def giveXs(list):
    answer=(list[::3])
    return answer
```

For y:

```
def giveYs(list):
    answer=(list[1::3])
    return answer
```

For z:

```
def giveZs(list):
    answer=(list[2::3])
    return answer
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write,

```
answer=(list[::3]+1)
```

You add 1 to list[::3]

You should write as

```
answer=(list[1::3])
```